# How to set delay timeout for each HTTP get on each button request

Tags: angularjs, http, timeout, delay

I have a button which fetches data from database.php. I'm trying to add a timeout delay BEFORE the http.get not response, so I can't use promise. In php, its so easy by using sleep(). As for the reason, its part of another project to simulate latency (I know you can do it via other means).

```
app.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
     $scope.requestData = function () {
        $scope.delta = '[waiting]';
        //Delay here!
        $http.get('database.php').then(function (response) {
            $scope.rows = response.data.records;
    };
});
```

I have tried, **doesn't work**:

```
app.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
     $scope.requestData = function () {
        $scope.delta = '[waiting]';
        $http.get('database.php',{ timeout: 3000 }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.rows = response.data.records;
    };
});
```

I have tried passing an empty timer, **doesn't work**:

```
app.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    var timer = function () {
    }

    $scope.requestData = function () {
        $scope.delta = '[waiting]';
        $timeout(timer, 3000);
        $http.get('database.php').then(function (response) {
            $scope.rows = response.data.records;
    };
});
```

Any ideas, what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the function which you want to delay into the timeout function like this

```
app.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
     $scope.requestData = function () {
        $scope.delta = '[waiting]';
        //Delay here!
        $timeout(function () {
            $http.get('database.php').then(function (response) {
                 $scope.rows = response.data.records;
            });
        }, 2000)
    };
});
```